# How to remove trailing forward slash from main domain URL or Home Page using .htaccess in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, trailing-slash

I will be very thankful if i get the solution to remove the trailing forward slash form the Home Page URL .

I am using ***custom page*** as ***Home Page*** for my site and the main URL is showing like **"example.com/"** and i want to remove that forward slash from my Home Page URL.

Here is my current WordPress .htaccess

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php74” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php74 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between "BEGIN WordPress" and "END WordPress" are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

I have tried with the wordpress settings :

**setting >> permalinks >> permalink structure >> custom structure >> /%postname%**

This method solves only to remove the post link forwarding slash from URL.
```

Comment: You _can't_ remove the slash at the domain root. https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/118752